# x:Name attribute value is not available in code behind

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to reference the listView in the code behind but it is not seen at all by Visual Studio. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Practice11.Views.ProfilePage"
             xmlns:circleImage="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions">
  <ListView x:Name="listView">
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10">
          <circleImage:CircleImage x:Name="image" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
          <Label Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

Everything should be fine. I've never experienced this. I've already tried to rebuild the project and restart Visual Studio, but none of these worked.

Comment: did you try to delete everything inside bin and obj folder for both android/ios and XF project? after deleting a rebuild also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problems, but I think you might have missed `<ListView.ItemTemplate>` between `<ListView>` and `<DataTemplate>`.

EDIT:
Also, based on the screenshot pasted below, you need to change the x:Class attribute value to "Practice11.Views.ActivitiesPage" to get it working.

Comment: It seemed awkward that Visual Studio marked everything from DataTemplate onwards as unnecessary, but this is apparently not the cause of the problem. ListView.ItemTemplate was necessary here, but did not solve my problem.

Comment: Maybe it's just a problem with intellisense? Have you tried writing all your code without intellisense and then compiling it?

Comment: This happens to me quite alot, closing all files, compiling them reopening usually does the trick.

Comment: @Dawid I tried doing that. Usually the variable is underlined with red when that happens, but this time it is all red

Comment: your xaml is called x:Class="Practice11.Views.ProfilePage" and code behind is ActivitiesPage!? how is that supposed to work in the world

Comment: @batmaci Yes, it is totally my fault because I copied code from one place to another...